# Select Input Doesn't Work With Textbox

Tags: php, html

When I fill out this form and submit the value nothing happens, but when I pass only 1 value at a time the value go through, so what am I doing wrong.

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<label for="kafli">Kafli:</label>
<select name="kafli" id="kafli">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="11">1.1</option>
    <option value="12">1.2</option>
    <option value="13">1.3</option>
    <option value="14">1.4</option>
    <option value="15">1.5</option>
    <option value="16">1.6</option>
</select>

<label for="html">HTML:</label>
<textarea name="html" id="html"></textarea>

<input type="submit" value="Deila">
</form>
```

PHP

```
if(isset($_POST['html'])) { 
    echo 'HTML is OK'; 
    if(isset($_POST['kafli'])) {
        echo 'Kafli is OK'; 
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP code?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['html'])) {
    echo 'HTML is OK';
    if(isset($_POST['kafli'])) {
        echo 'Kafli is OK';
    }
}

Comment: put that in your question not in comments and all of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to echo both conditions to ensure they're not empty, then use `empty()` and not `isset()`.

Using `<select>` and `<textarea>` already assumes they're "set". What you're looking to use and being the better method, is a conditional `empty()`.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['html'])) { 
        echo 'HTML is OK'; 
        if(!empty($_POST['kafli'])) {
            echo 'Kafli is OK'; 
        } 
     }

    else{
    echo "one or all are empty";
    }

} // brace for submit
```

While naming your submit button: (for the added conditional statement I added in the first example)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Deila">
```

Or, use a conditional statement for both, using the `&& - AND` operator:

I.e.:

```
if(!empty($_POST['html']) && !empty($_POST['kafli'])) {
    echo 'Both are filled.'; 

    } 

    else{
        echo "One or both were not filled";
    }
```

Or, using the `OR - ||` operator

```
if(!empty($_POST['html']) || !empty($_POST['kafli'])) {
echo "One was filled, but not the other";
    }
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php